# array_merge for Maps and Vectors at hacklang

Tags: vector, dictionary, hhvm, hacklang

Given the following code

```
<?hh
$a = Vector {"qux"};
$b = Vector {"foo","bar"};

$a = array_merge($a, $b);
```

The following error is raised:

> Warning: Invalid operand type was used: array_merge expects array(s)

Is there any workaround for `array_merge` for vectors and maps, without making a foreach by hand, of the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my self.

In fact `array_merge` is not listed under the list of [functions with support for hack Collections](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.collections.phpbuiltins.php).

The best way to merge Vectors is the function [addAll](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.vectortv.addall.php).

```
<?hh
$a = Vector {"qux"};
$b = Vector {"foo","bar"};

$a->addAll($b);

var_dump($a);
```

In the case of Map, it's a bit more complicated and a combination of foreach and addAll is required to set the Pair `<Tk,Tv>`

Answer (score 1):

Well I wanted to merge a map, and found out you could also use the `setAll()` method.

```
$this->params->setAll($parent->params);
```

The `params` of the `$parent` overwrite the keys of `$this->params`